# How do I get milliseconds details on google spreadsheet using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

this is my app script function where I am updating the google spreadsheets. I am getting the all the Html user filled data separated by "/".
 I am sending a response from an Html page to google spreadsheet and want to 
    get the milliseconds details on date object, to avoid the overwriting.

```
Let's say if multiple people are submitting at once then, I can get only 
the last entry because the date object is created with mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss 
format and if multiple people are submitting at the same instance of time 
like ( 4 people are submitting at 03/03/2020 04:55:55) then I will be 
getting the last submitted record and other records will be overwritten by 
the last record. 

Can anyone of you help me with this?  How should I solve this requirement?
```

Please find my javascript function from the HTML page where I am calling google app script API to run the function userClick written in app script. 
    `function sendData(u_wk_Det)
    {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) 
    {console.log(response);})
        .withFailureHandler(function(err){console.log(err);})
        .userClick(u_wk_Det);
    }`

```
/*code shown below is my app script function using which I am updating the google spreadsheets.*/

`function userClick(u_wk_det)
      {
       Logger.log('table data - ');
       var ss = 
       SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid').getSheetByName('Sheet2');
       var Srow = 2;
       var Lrow = ss.getLastRow();
       var Lcol = ss.getLastColumn();
       var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, Lrow  , Lcol).getValues().filter(function(o) 
       {return o !=="" });
       for(i in data)
       {  

        var j=i;
        j++;
        j++;
        var Crow = data[i];
        if (Crow[0]=='')
        {
             var dt = new Date();
             Logger.log(dt);
             Logger.log(Crow[0]);
              if(u_wk_det!=="")
                { 
                    var user_week_details = u_wk_det.split("/"); 
                    ss.getRange(j,1).setValue(dt);
                    ss.getRange(j,2).setValue(user_week_details[0]);
                    ss.getRange(j,3).setValue(user_week_details[1]);
                    ss.getRange(j,4).setValue(user_week_details[2]);
                }
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Can you share some code example? What do you mean "sending response from an Html page to google spreadsheet"? JavaScript Date objects have millisecond precision so that should work for your use-case. I'm not following where the data is coming from, where its going, and how you're using it after.

Comment: It sounds like you could fix this by changing the way you write data to the sheet, it shouldn't need to rely on the time of submission as a unique identifier. We will need to see the code that sends the data, the code that receives the data, and the code that reads & writes to the sheet to understand where the problem lies here.

Comment: hi @CameronRoberts,
I have provided my code in the question.

Comment: Hi @IMTheNachoMan,
"sending response from an Html page to google spreadsheet" means whatever data is filled by the user on the Html page upon clicking the submit button javascript function will collect all the details and it will call the app script function from the app script.